# Kivy reStructuredText renderer popup?

Tags: python, popup, kivy, restructuredtext

i want popup effect for references in kivy reStructuredText renderer, in default when we press any reference it scrolls to the reference, here i want to replace scroll with a popup, i have been searching for this for a long time but in vain, today i found  `goto(ref, *largs)`in kivy docs, is it possible to call a reference popup using this? is it possible to redefine RstDocument fuctions in another class and use it?? i am a beginner.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<RSTGUI>:
    RstDocument:
        text: root.doc
        goto: # Any Popup aur bubble with reference
""")

class RSTGUI(BoxLayout):
    doc="""
.. _top:

Hello world
===========

This is an **emphased text**, some ``interpreted text``.
And this is a reference to top_::

    $ print("Hello world")


"""
class RST(App):
    def build(self):
        return RSTGUI()


if __name__=='__main__':
    RST().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

After little research i have figured it out, Alhumdolillah.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.rst import RstDocument
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

Builder.load_string("""

<RSTGUI>:
    MyRST:
        text: root.doc




<about_us_popup>:
    size_hint: 0.8,0.6
    title: "About Us"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:'vertical'
        RstDocument:
            text: "MyText"
        Button:
            text:"OK"
            size_hint: 1,0.1
            on_press:root.dismiss()



""")



class RSTGUI(BoxLayout):

    doc="""
.. _top:

Hello world
===========

This is an **emphased text**, some ``interpreted text``.
And this is a reference to top_::

    $ print("Hello world")

"""

class MyRST(RstDocument):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyRST, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.about_us_popup = about_us_popup()

    def goto(self, ref, *largs):
        self.about_us_popup.open()


class RST(App):
    def build(self):
        return RSTGUI()


class about_us_popup(Popup):
    pass

if __name__=='__main__':
    RST().run()
```